# Confusion about force

Tags: forces, physical-constants

While proving F=m.a,we get something like F=k.m.a but we somehow equal k to 1 and just write it in former way.Why is k=1?
In the similar way,why can't we do it for other constants like Gravitational constant(G)?Sorry for the dumb question.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose we write:

$$ F  = k\,ma \tag{1}$$

Then we can choose the units of force to make the constant of proportionality equal to unity. That is we fix our units for mass, distance and time then we define the Newton to be the force that accelerates one kilogram by one metre per second squared. And this is of course what we do.

But suppose we now consider the gravitational force given by:

$$ F = \frac{GMm}{r^2} \tag{2} $$

The acceleration this produces is calculated by combining our two equations i.e.

$$ ma = \frac{GMm}{r^2} $$

and this rearranges to an expression for $G$:

$$ G = \frac{ar^2}{M} \tag{3} $$

But the problem here is that we already chosen out units of mass, distance and time to make $k=1$ so there's no way we can just set $G=1$. We could start with equation (2) and choose our units of mass, distance and time to make $G$ equal to one, but if we did that then we'd had $k \ne 1$ in equation (1). Whatever we do we can't make both $k=1$ and $G=1$.

There are lots of constants in physics that have dimensions i.e. have units that involve mass, distance and/or time. We can choose our definitions of the kilogram, metre and second to make some of these equal to unity, but that necessarily forces other constants to be different from unity.

Answer (score 1):

You don't "prove" it.. it's defined that way. Here, suppose you were Newton trying to explain the universe:

Suppose you push something. You see that as you push "harder" it accelerates faster. So you introduce a concept $F$ of force. So you write $a \propto F$. You also notice that stuff with more mass (call it $m$), whatever that means, accelerates slower for the same force. So you write $a \propto \frac{1}{m}$.

End the end this gives $ a \propto \frac{F}{m} $. You write the proportionality constant as $\frac{1}{k}$.

So $ a=\frac{F}{km}$, which gives $F=kma$.

But you can just go back a redefine what you meant by "mass" to include the k:

$F=m^*a$, where $m^* = mk$ is now our new definiton for "mass". Now just get rid of the initial idea of mass that you had and replace it with the new one. So don't $m^*$ and just write $m$ to mean the new mass.

So: $F=ma$

---

Please realize that this is a hand-waving argument. At the end of the day, $F=ma$ is an axiom/postulate/theory, whatever you want to call it.

You assumed something called force, mass, acceleration exists and you give it some definitions and build a theory from it that seems to explain the universe pretty well.

Comment: What is this "k"? I have never seen it before.

Comment: It's a proportionality constant. It's just math.  When you know, "y is proportional to x" a.k.a $ y \propto x$, that is the same as $y=kx$ where k is some constant such that the equality holds.

Comment: What is this for? I've only seen things written as F = ma

Comment: The point is simply that proportionality constants will show up and it's just a matter of where you insert them. If I don't absorb the constants into $m$, that works. If I don't, other physics equations will absorb them.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Newton's second law of motion states that the force applied on a body is proportional to rate of change in the body's momentum.

```
F ∝ dP/dt
F = k.d(mv)/dt
  = k{m.dv/dt + v.dm/dt}
  = km.dv/dt           ( dm/dt = 0)
  = km.a
```

According to Newton, When a force of 1N is applied on a body of mass 1 kg, the body accelerates by 1ms^-2 and vice versa. (The direction of acceleration determines the direction of force and vice versa. They have the same direction.
To be more precise the direction of acceleration is same as that of NET external force.)

So Newton defined k=1 when all the units are in their standard form i.e, SI units.

```
Therefore, F = m.a
```